# Iterating over a ManytoMany field and comparing values with another iteration not working as expected

Tags: python, django

I have two models. The `Course` model has a many-to-many field related to the `Student` model.

Problem is, when I iterate through the `course.student` and iterate trough the `students` to compare if values are same, there are too many iterations.

Basically a list of students is normally displayed in my template, and when I submit the form, the Course.student field is updated by one. So when iteration starts again, there will be 2 students to compare, which will display more students per page each time. I need to find a way to display the checked students just one time, otherwise display the form.

```
{% for crs_stud in course.student.all %}
  {% for student in students %}
    {% if crs_stud == student %}
      <p>{{ student.name.upper }} is already enrolled.</p>
    {% else %}
      <form action="." method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="id_{{ student.id }}">{{ student.name }}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{ student_id }}"
          value="{{ student.id }}"
          name="student_ids">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only need a single loop through the students.

```
{% with crs_stud=course.student.all %}
{% for student in students %}
  {% if student in crs_stud %}
    <p>{{ student.name.upper }} is already enrolled.</p>
  {% else %}
    // display enrollment form
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

The `{% with %}` tag isn't required here, but will prevent duplicate queries.

You might want to try to move this logic out of the template and into your view/helper functions/model methods. For example, you could pass two lists to the template, `enrolled_students` and `unenrolled_students`, then loop through both lists in the template.

Comment: I had to modify it a bit, and now the form button displays for every entry. Before, the form was supposed to allow multiple select. This is how it initially looked: https://pastebin.com/dU93mDPZ Any clue ?

Comment: You’ve already marked this question as answered, so it won’t get very much attention. If you want the button to appear once, then you need to move it outside of the loop.

Comment: Yeah but still it will save one object at a time. Thought you could have an idea, otherwise maybe tomorrow I will post a different question.

Comment: How it saves objects depends on the view as well, so that’s a completely separate question.